# shell_exec php com acento

Tags: php, shell

Preciso rodar um comando via *shell* que pode ter acento (envolve nome de arquivo) pelo PHP. Imprimindo o comando e rodando ele na mão ele roda com o acento, porém com o `shell_exec` ele não roda. Se eu tiro o acento do nome do arquivo ele roda o comando certo com o `shell_exec`, mas eu realmente não posso mudar o nome do arquivo.

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);

    $path = "C:\\Users\\gabriela.mattos\\Desktop\\audios\\";

    $diretorio = dir($path);
    while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){

       if ($arquivo != "." && $arquivo != ".."){
           $arquivo2= (utf8_encode($arquivo));

           $arquivo2 = str_replace(" ","_",$arquivo2);
           $arquivoConvertido = str_replace(".mp3",".avi",$arquivo2);

           echo shell_exec(utf8_encode("ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i C:\\Users\\gabriela.mattos\\Pictures\\logo.jpg -i ".$path.$arquivo2." -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec mjpeg ".$path.$arquivoConvertido.""));
    }
}
$diretorio -> close();
?>
```

Comment: Criei uma maquina virtual com ubuntu e joguei tudo para lá.
Mudei os caminhos e tudo mais e funcionou.
Fiz isso sabendo que o Linux trata a acentuação de forma diferente.